# What Mongodb schema and collection is good for three levels of nesting in my University app

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am designing schema mongoose schema and collection I want little help because there are three levels of nesting in my case.

Case Scenario:

1. We have department in my university. See the screenshot - where we have first dropdown which will be Physics, Chemistry, Mathmatics.
2. Now under department we have main folder that is one to many relationship meaning one department have many mainfolders. Professor can select their department and add mainfolder if they want.
3. Under mainfolder we have subfolders that have one to many relationship with the mainfolder.
4. Finally professor can select department, main folder, sub folders, files and submit the records.
5. One thing is important that we are only saving upload file name in mongodb. Actual file with content is saved in AWS s3 bucket.

[image]

Question is how we should construct the schema to avoid aggregate or joins.
Can we create two collection one have department, mainfolders, subfolders 
and other collection have all the saved records i.e. when professor add the file and hit submit.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have designed this application using only two collections. We can manage in one collection however there is loads of duplicate records. These duplicate records were not worth and slow down once record is 500 plus.

Collection 1: University, Department, Main folder, Sub folder with ids.

Collection 2: File data reference with university and sub folder ids.

**Collection 1 Schema:**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d43489e1c6d3742443ff457"),
        "subjectid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
        "subjectname" : "Physics",
        "createdby" : "Einstien",
        "createdon" : ISODate("2019-08-01T21:29:49.231Z"),
        "mainfolders" : [ 
            {
                "folderid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
                "foldername" : "Theory of Relativity",
                "createdby" : "Einstien",
                "createdon" : ISODate("2019-08-01T21:29:49.231Z"),
                "subfolders" : [ 
                    {
                      "subfolderid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
                       "subfoldername" : "Velocity of light",
                        "createdBy" : "Einstien",
                        "createdOn" : ISODate("2019-08-01T21:29:49.231Z"),
                    }, 
                    {
                        "subfolderid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
                        "subfoldername" : "Energy to mass relation",
                        "createdBy" : "Einstien",
                        "createdOn" : ISODate("2019-08-01T21:29:49.231Z"),
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Collection 2 Schema:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d48710d5cd1ad179886dbb6"),
    "filename" : "Theory of relativity.pdf",
    "contentdesc" : "The theory of relativity usually encompasses two interrelated theories by Albert Einstein: special relativity and general relativity......whole content....."
    "createdby" : "Ben",
    "createdon" : ISODate("2019-08-05T18:10:22.447Z"),
    "folder" : "5d4359cd5cd1ad179886dbaf",
    "subjectid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
    "folderid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
    "subfolderid" : ObjectId("5ce31c4fa3bfd856d880c13c"),
}
```

This design leverages:

1. Easy to add departments, folders and sub-folders without duplicate records.
2. Easy to store 1: * relations in file in separate collection with reference to keys. MongoDB documentation says to normalize the records in case of duplicacy. [link here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding)
3. No need to use distinct while fetching University departments, folders.

That's how I design this problem any optimization suggestion is welcomed.